# Scrapy, how to extract parent li only except child li

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a site[URL : https://www.khaasfood.com/shop/]
First I found I have to get categories with a hierarchy.

.container has a list of li tags that is the parent category.

Each parent category may have a children's li tag.

First I have to take parent categories. but how?
'''
response.css('.container li .cat-item')
'''
this code returns all li tags which means bot parent and child category.

Answer (score 1):

`.container > li.cat-item` would only select li tags which are the child of `.container` element

`.container li.cat-item` css selector without `>` will select all descendant `li` tags